# Android In-app robotmedia: Restore Transactions

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to implement an in-app purchase functionality with the help of the net.robotmedia.billing library.

The purchase of an in-app item (managed) works: the purchase is made, there's an order in google checkout, and later when I restart the device for example, when restoring the transactions the "purchase" state can be retrieved.

When I uninstall and reinstall the app, after restoring the transactions the purchase state can be detected. However, this time something (probably the Market app) sends a "Purchase failed"-notification. The transaction history (after a purchase) always is:
8x `Transaction.PurchaseState.CANCELLED` followed by one `Transaction.PurchaseState.PURCHASED`.

The "Purchase failed."-notification is sent even though no purchase has been made. In the initialization I do:

```
BillingController.setConfiguration(mConfiguration);
BillingController.registerObserver(myBillingObserver);
...
BillingController.checkBillingSupported(this);
BillingController.restoreTransactions(this);
```

Everything seems to work, only that I get this notification. How do I get rid of this notification? Or is there perhaps something I might have missed?

**UPDATE**: The above mentioned cancelled transactions are just the history which is correct. Still the market app (I assume) sends a "Purchase failed"-notification on RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS (I assume when I receive these cancelled transactions).

Perhaps this is not important since a user does not cancel, re-purchase, cancel, re-purchase, etc. But once a transaction is cancelled, the user will receive this notification whenever the restoring is processed which is annoying (and confusing for the user).

Comment: Is is managed purchase or unmanaged? You can login to google wallet with account you did purchase and check your transaction.

Comment: @Ankit: thanks. It WAS managed, I think. It's been a while since that. I got to see that later too.

Answer (score 3):

try to use InApp version3.0, the reference is available [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/12/in-app-billing-version-3.html).
the google team made it very easy to developers. there is no service at all, really simple and it was working pretty good to me....

Comment: Currently I don't work on Android, but once I have time I will check it out. It does look a lot easier. +1 for the link.